# Should I use breadth first or depth first for searching a filesystem for a predetermined number of errors?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have a large filesystem that I need to traverse for errors.  Each file knows whether or not it contains an error, so I simply need to travel to each node and check whether there is an error there.  Also, each directory knows the total number of errors that exists within, so a search can be terminated once the given number of errors is found, and a directory need not be traversed if it does not contain errors.

My question is whether the better solution to this would be to use a depth first or a breadth first search.  The height of the tree is undefined, which I know usually makes BFS better, but given that we know if a directory will contain an error before traversing it, I am not sure if that advantage is mitigated.

NOTE: This is **NOT** a homework assignment.  It is a requirement for a script that my boss has requested that I write.

EDIT 1: Time efficiency is far more important than space efficiency, as the script will primarily be run overnight, and therefore can essentially use all of the system memory, if necessary.

EDIT 2: Though is seems the popular answer is BFS for my problem, I am having trouble understanding why it would not be a DFS problem.  Since (A) all errors need eventually be reached and (B) we know if a directory contains errors, BFS's protection against rabbit holes does not really apply.  With that in mind, the only real difference seems to be space used, which would make DFS better.  Can anyone give a good argument as to why this is not the case?

Comment: Does each directory know how many errors are in all of its subdirectories, or just in its immediate directory? Do you have to note what the errors are (i.e. find each file that has the errors) or just note what subtree those errors are in?

Comment: He says a directory need not be traversed if it does not contain errors, which implies they know all subdirectories.

Comment: If you know all the subdirectories, then what's the point of going more than one level deep? That is, there's no need for depth-first search then.

Comment: I need a full file path for every file containing an error, which is why I need to go as deep as necessary to reach the file. And yes, each directory knows the errors for all subdirectories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on a few stuff.

- Could your directories contain links and would you traverse the links? In that case, is it possible for the links to make a loop? In such a case, BFS makes more sense if you want to ignore the cycle-checking. Otherwise, it makes no difference.
- How is the distribution of errors? Could it be that one directory contains most errors while others are almost empty of errors? In that case BFS is more likely to end sooner because it searches all directories little by little. In such a case, you would spend a long time with DFS in one huge directory tree that contains say 1 error in the very bottom leaves only to find out the next directory contained all the bugs you need right at level 1. If the errors are distributed more evenly, again, it doesn't matter what you use.
- How big is your structure? If you have a tree with branching factor n (n subdirectories per each directory) and the tree has depth d, the BFS could take `O(d^n)` memory, while DFS could be written in such a way that it takes only `O(d)` memory (or in a simpler implementation `O(d*n)`) which in real huge directories could make a difference.

My general feeling reading your question is BFS, but it is still you who have to decide based on the properties of your problem.

Comment: As for point#2, he says that each directory knows the total number of errors in all subdirectories, so skipping is trivial.  A tree with a branching factor `n` would cause BFS to take up to `O(n^d)`, but that turns out to be remarkably rare in practice, especially since it would only do that if all the errors were in the leaves.

Comment: @MooingDuck, Alright I'll fix the 2nd point so it would show that the reasoning is still the same

Comment: About the BFS taking up a lot of space, I'm just pointing out the differences. It depends on him to decide if his directories meet these conditions or not.

Comment: About #3: If I have 10 subdirectories per directory, root is 1, then 10, then 100..., which is 10^0, 10^1, 10^2..., do that's `O(n^d)`.  You should probably also add that DFS is much easier to code.

Comment: The size of the structure is essentially unlimited.  As of right now there are over 400k files. The depth is unknown, and also unlimited. As for distribution of errors, it is unknown.  However, in response to your 2nd point, I need to find EVERY error, which means that spending a large amount of time on one deep error is an unfortunate necessity.

Comment: @MooingDuck, to me it's not that different. Take a node from queue/stack, process, add its children to a queue/stack. It's basically the same code (unless you write DFS with a recursive function)

Comment: @ewok, since every node needs to be visited, then DFS and BFS would spend the same amount of time processing. The space is also not an issue, because if you have 400k files, in the worst case you have only 800k nodes (each directory 2 files) (that is unless you have directories that contain only one directory or one file, but they only add space linearly) The only difference would be the way they access the hard disk etc. I'm not sure which one would actually be better, but MooingDuck's comment on the other post suggests BFS is better for filesystems.

Comment: @Shahbaz The current size of the filesystem is 400k, but it is expected to grow, which is why efficiency is so important.  as per your 3rd bullet point, you point out that BFS runs with  `O(d^n)`, as opposed to `O(d)` for DFS.  The branching factor of my filesystem can be quite large, and the depth is essentially unbounded, which makes `O(d^n)` far worse, as n could potentially be equal to the number of nodes there are total.

Comment: @ewok, no you got it all wrong. `d^n` is for a tree full of nodes  with branching factor `n` and depth `d`. This value is given if you don't know the number of elements in the tree. If you do, then BFS needs roughly `the biggest number of elements in a row`. So if you have these many nodes in different levels: 1 10 40 32 9 105 23 18, then BFS needs 105 nodes at maximum. Since no level can have more than 400k nodes, then BFS won't use more than that regardless of how deep the tree goes

Comment: @ewok: Yeah, `O(d^n)` memory is if every folder less than height `d` on the tree has `n` folders, which is a pretty bizarre case.  In practice, BFS tends to required less than 400 or so.  On the other hand, DFS is the same speed in every case, if you're finding _all_ the elements.

Answer (score 1):

From the requirements, I would recommend a breadth-first search, which is faster in general for node-based structures, and (I'm pretty sure) this situation as well.

Breadth-first searches are faster for node-based structures due to improved cache performance, even though it must maintain a "to-do" list.  This makes breadth-first the recommendation for directory searching.  Since your algorithm is a search algorithm, I would go with the general recommendation here.

Comment: Much improved cache performance.  [Google "breadth first vs depth first filesystem"](http://www.google.com/search?q=bredth+first+vs+depth+first+filesystem) for many many posts saying so.

Comment: Read this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/51456/15759

Comment: I think you used the term "cache" instead of "locality of reference" for seek and garbage collection, maybe? e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheney%27s_algorithm

Comment: I used cache as shorthand for [System paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)), which is _why_ locality of reference matters.  Nothing here has any relation to garbage collection, I'm not sure why you'd bring that up.

Comment: "Cheney's algorithm is a stop and copy method of tracing garbage collection in computer software systems... this is known as a breadth-first list copying garbage collection scheme."

Comment: @Forethinker: I'm really trying here, but I'm confused.  I totally get that Cheney's is one thing implemented with a breadth first search, but so are many many other things. When dealing with the filesystem, the OS is caching disk pages in memory, which is why I used the word "cache".

Answer (score 0):

If the directory or filesystem structure's width is greater than depth, then DFS, otherwise, BFS for memory constraints:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23478084/986067

[If the depth (or height) is unknown and potentially infinite, DFS (preorder) will never complete the search, while BFS will.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Infinite_trees)

Also if the files you are looking for are user-generated, then it is expected to be located relatively close to the root, so BFS.

If there are symlinks or network drives that are not handled properly and could cause a loop, DFS for the cycle detection.

In a real-world scenario? [Iterative Deepening DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search), where the depth-limited DFS adjust its depth limit, mimicking BFS's completeness while retaining its space efficiency characteristics. It only tracks of its current path.